# How to pair ibeacon with iOS first time programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, ibeacon

I started with ibeacon-based(actually— lock) device development+iOS application. I can provide to iOS app the minor and major+ UUID of beacon. But, it is good only for testing.

And what if the customer bought my device and want to pair with self.iOS application. For having a unique key to opening/closing device? Sure, i can write in code the common major/minor for all my devices, but it is foolish and insecure, right? Any user with my app can open the lock with 1 tap.

So, can you help me to understand how i can pair 1 unique iPhone with 1 unique ibeacon(but they all mine) to have an 1 unique pair to communicate?

I need to do it at the 1st time after unboxing the lock.

Comment: PS Sorry for my barbarian English, it is not my even second language-)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you require the user to register to a web service after app installation, and then download the UUID/major/minor from the web service and store the identifiers in the app?

If you are distributing user-specific hardware beacons, you can have an activation code associated with each beacon that is entered as part of the registration process. One code must be tied to a UUID/major/minor on the back end.

Keep in mind that once the beacon is transmitting, anybody can read the beacon identifiers over the air using Android, Linux or OSX.  So make sure your system is adequately secure.